# Parsing file stats returned by Rbox execute command

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm fairly new to Ruby programming and right now I'm using Rbox/Rye to write some test automation ruby scripts.
As part of the testing a customer uploads a +10GB file to an ftp host.
The script, every minute, checks if the file is still being uploaded, the upload completed or the upload failed.
For the test I use Rbox/Rye execute shell command to find the file statistics:

```
def check_file_upload()
    rbox = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")
    rbox.disable_safe_mode
    result = rbox.execute "stat #{@file}"
end

stats = file.check_file_upload()
puts stats
```

The "puts" prints the file stats correctly. The same format as if I execute the "stat file" command on a linux host.
Now, is there a way that I can actually parse the value returned by
    check_file_upload()
method. Can I use Ruby's built in regex, or maybe grep/awk, to pick specific information from the returned file statistics.
The following is file statistics:

```
File: `/home/user/file_name.dmp'  
Size: 11594768384   Blocks: 22668184   IO Block: 4096   regular file  
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 57442314    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1504/user)   Gid: ( 1504/user)  
Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700  
Modify: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700  
Change: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700
```

More specifically, I would like to pick out the file size, Access, Modify and Change values

Comment: As an additional note.  The file stats returned is not stored in a file (might not be able to use grep/awk) but in a local variable.  So, is it possible then to use Ruby regex to pick out the above mentioned values?

Comment: Ok, made some progress. I was able to parse the return Size index location value, the place where "Size" is listed in the return value:     size_value = /Size/ =~ stats.to_s      I guess now I have to figure out how to pull the actual "Size" value but since I have the "Size" index location value it should be doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would be a simple task for regular expressions.  Here is a class that parses the interesting bits from that "stat" string and exposes them as attributes:

```
class FileStatInfo
  attr_reader :size, :access, :modify, :change
  def initialize(string)
    string.split(/\n/).each do |line|
      if line =~ /^Size:\s*(\d+)/
        @size = $1.to_i
      elsif line =~ /^Access:\s*(.*)/
        @access = $1.strip # Or Date.parse($1.strip)
      # ...
      end
    end
  end
end

# ...

stat_info = FileStatInfo.new(file.check_file_upload)
stat_info.size # => 11594768384
stat_info.access # => "2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked great. Just needed to make one change, had to cast the method return value to a string first before splitting it:  string.to_s.split(/\n/).each do |line|

Answer (score 0):

Once the string `str` has been extracted with `check_file_upload()` a hash can be built to hold the values of interest.

**Code**

```
def extract(str, keepers)
  r = /\w+:\s(?:\S+\s)*\S+/
  str.lines.each_with_object({}) do |line, h|
    line.scan(r).each do |s|
      k,_,v = s.partition(/:\s+/)
      v = v.to_i if v =~ /^\d+$/
      h.update({ k=>[v] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } if keepers.include?(k)
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

I understand the following is typical of the string produced by `check_file_upload()`:

```
str =
"Size: 11594768384   Blocks: 22668184   IO Block: 4096   regular file  
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 57442314    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1504/user)   Gid: ( 1504/user)  
Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700  
Modify: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700  
Change: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700"
```

The array `keepers` identifies the data to be extracted from this string:

```
keepers = %w{ Size Access Modify Change }
  #=> ["Size", "Access", "Modify", "Change"]

extract(str, keepers)
  #=> {"Size"=>[11594768384],
  #    "Access"=>["(0644/-rw-r--r--)", "2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"],
  #    "Modify"=>["2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700"],
  #    "Change"=>["2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700"]}
```

**Explanation**

Our regular expression is:

```
r = /\w+:\s(?:\S+\s)*\S+/
```

For the example above:

```
str.lines
  #=> ["Size: 11594768384   Blocks: 22668184   IO Block: 4096  regular file \n",
  #    "Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 57442314    Links: 1\n",
  #    "Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1504/user)   Gid: ( 1504/user)  \n",
  #    "Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700  \n",
  #    "Modify: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700  \n",
  #    "Change: 2015-01-06 11:38:59.000000000 -0700"]
```

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) creates an initially-empty hash represented by the block variable `h`, and passes each element of the array `str.lines` into the block, assigning it to the block variable `line`. Initially,

```
line = "Size: 11594768384   Blocks: 22668184   IO Block: 4096  regular file \n"
h = {}
```

Within the block we compute:

```
a = line.scan(r)
  #=> ["Size: 11594768384", "Blocks: 22668184", "Block: 4096"]
```

Note that `"IO Block: 4096   regular file"` was extracted incorrectly, but that is of no matter since that field is not needed.

```
a.each do |s|
  k,_,v = s.partition(/:\s+/)
  v = v.to_i if v =~ /^\d+$/
  h.update({ k=>[v] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } if keepers.include?(k)
end

h #=> {"Size"=>[11594768384]}
```

Here, the first string `each` passes into its block is

```
s = "Size: 11594768384"
```

so

```
k,_,v = s.partition(/:\s+/)
  #=> ["Size", ": ", "11594768384"]
v =~ /^\d+$/ #=> 0 
v = v.to_i if v =~ /^\d+$/
  #=> 11594768384
h.update({ k=>[v] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } if keepers.include?(k)
  #=> {}.update({ "Size"=>[11594768384] }) if
  #     ["Size", "Access", "Modify", "Change"].include?("Size")
  #=> true
h #=> { "Size=>[11594768384] }
```

We use the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that uses a block to resolve the values of keys contained in both of the hashes being merged.

As `keepers` includes neither `"Blocks"` nor `"Block"`, the hashes for those keys are not merged into `h`.

For next element of `str.lines`:

```
line = "Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 57442314    Links: 1\n"
```

contains no keys in `keepers`, so nothing is added to the hash `h`. The following line:

```
line = "Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1504/user)   Gid: ( 1504/user)  \n"
```

adds `{ "Access"=>["(0644/-rw-r--r--)"] }` to the hash, so we then have:

```
h = { "Size"=>[11594768384], "Access"=>["(0644/-rw-r--r--)"] }
```

Next,

```
line = "Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700  \n"
```

so

```
a = line.scan(r)
  #=> ["Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"]
```

The only element `each` passes into its block from this array is:

```
s = "Access: 2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"

k,_,v = s.partition(/:\s+/)
  #=> ["Access", ": ", "2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"] 
v =~ /^\d+$/
  #=> nil 
v = v.to_i if v =~ /^\d+$/ # no conversion to integer
h.update({ k=>[v] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } if keepers.include?(k)
  #=> {"Size"=>[11594768384],
  #    "Access"=>["(0644/-rw-r--r--)", "2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"]}
```

As `h` already contains the key `k => Access"`, `update`'s block is called up to determine the value of `"Access"` after the merge is performed. The three block variables are:

```
k = "Access" # not used, so replaced with an underscore
ov = ["(0644/-rw-r--r--)"                    # "old" value
nv = ["2015-01-06 11:32:17.000000000 -0700"] # "new" value
```

The value of `"Access"` is to be the sum of the arrays `ov` and `nv`, as shown above.

The remaining elements of `str.lines` are processed similarly.